# Values not passed back after dismissModalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm passing a string variable for the sake of testing (isLoggedIn) as well as an NSManagedObject (userObject).  However, when I dismiss the VC and it comes back to the root, I do not have the new data that was set in the variables in the loginViewController.

```
LoginViewController *loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
loginVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
loginVC.userObject = self.userObject;
loginVC.isLoggedIn = self.isLoggedIn;

[self presentModalViewController:loginVC animated:YES];
[loginVC release];
```

I later dismiss the view with:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Update:

Ended up using delegates as someone suggested.  I used the following post as a guideline:

[UIViewController parentViewController access properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412688/uiviewcontroller-parentviewcontroller-access-properties)

Comment: I believe you need to use delegate for this.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what data you're talking about? You're using a correct way of showing the view controller in a modal way, but I'd add a delegate field in the LoginViewController class and set that to the calling class. Also, if you're making changes in Core Data, don't forget to save them with a context save call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using delegates as someone above suggested.  I used the following post as a guideline:

[UIViewController parentViewController access properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412688/uiviewcontroller-parentviewcontroller-access-properties)

Answer (score 0):

I may not be following you properly so this could be irrelevant.

I am guessing you mean that:

1. You set your ivars after `alloc`/`init`
2. You make some changes inside `LoginViewController`
3. You expect those changes to be reflected in `self.userObject` and `self.isLoggedIn` of the class that instantiated `LoginViewController`

which may or may not happen if you act on the objects themselves or you reassign the pointers

e.g.

If you call `self.userObject.name = @"Test";` inside `LoginViewController` then the change will be reflected in the class that instantiated `LoginViewController` and `LoginViewController` because the ivars are pointing to the same object in memory and you are manipulating the object.

**OR**

If you call `self.userObject = theResultOfSomeNewFetch;` then the change will not be reflected as you now have a pointer in `LoginViewController` that is pointing to a different `userObject` to the pointer in the class that called `LoginViewController`

Hopefully I have not lost the plot completely and this is somewhere near what you mean.

Comment: Yeah this is my thought exactly.  If you say stringA=stringB and then say stringB=@"my new string" stringB will be assigned a new pointer so stringA will no longer be pointing to stringB, so you won't see the new value reflected.  If you used a mutable string for example then you can change the value of stringB without allocing a new string and therefore assigning it a new pointer.